# Depression of a car

Tags: trigonometry

> A person on the summit of mountain observes that the angles of depression of a car moving on a straight road at three consecutive mile stones are x, y and z respectively. Prove that the height of the mountain is $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\cot^2x-2\cot^2y+\cot^2z}}$

I am getting the height as $\frac{1}{\cot y-\cot z}$ or as $\frac{1}{\cot x - \cot y}$. Not getting the desired expression.

Comment: You assumed that if we drop perpendicular from the summit to the foot of the mountain and connect that point with the first milestone, the other two milestones are going to be on that line. What if this is not the case? Do you have a drawing for this problem?

Comment: @Vasya- I see your point. Thanks. I have redrawn the figure now. But still not able to solve it. I don't know how to utilize the milestone information here. I know that gives us distance as 1 mile. But not able to form any equation with that.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Let the distance between the foot of the mountain and the first mile stone be $a$ . Then the distances between the foot of the mountain and the consecutive milestones are $a+1$ and $a+2$.

Now $\cot x = \frac{a}{h} \ , \cot y = \frac{a+1}{h} \ , \cot z = \frac{a+2}{h}$.

$$\frac{2}{\cot^2x - 2\cot^2y + \cot^2z} = \frac{2}{\frac{a^2}{h^2}-2\frac{a^2+2a+1}{h^2}+\frac{a^2+4a+4}{h^2}} = \frac{2h^2}{a^2-2a^2-4a-2+a^2+4a+4} = \frac{2h^2}{2}$$

Thus,

$$\sqrt{\frac{2}{\cot^2x - 2\cot^2y + \cot^2z}}  = h$$